# Spring execute a block of code after a delay

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring boot controller which makes two service calls. The second call should occur only after 10 secs, after getting response from first call.

```
public SomeResponse myAction() {
    res = serviceCallA();
    waitFor(10) {
        serviceCallB();
    }
    return res;
}
```

The action doesn't have to wait for the response from serviceCallB(), to return response. Call to serviceCallB() just has to be triggered in separate thread.

Whats the best way to implement this? I need something like a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, but with a delay.

Sample code would awesome..

Comment: Just use an async thread as you have suggested but include the sleep 10 seconds in the async call.

Comment: for java 8 you can use [completablefuture](http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/)

Comment: Spring Integration has a more robust aproach https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/delayer.adoc

Answer (score 4):

Use a promise, not the horrible `Thread.sleep` from 1999 that wastes precious system resources. Your options are [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), [RxJava Publisher constructs](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html#conversion-between-types), Spring's own [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/learn).

Let `serviceCallA` return `Mono<Something>` (Project Reactor). Then:

```java
res.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
  .doOnEach(unused -> serviceCallB())
  .block();
```

There's probably 6 ways to do this in each library, the above being one.

Answer (score 4):

With java.util.concurrent package you have the Executors

```java
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ex.schedule(() -> serviceCallB, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward answer;

```
SomeResponse myAction() {
  res = serviceCallA();
  serviceCallB();
  return res;
}

@Async
void serviceCallB() {
  Thread.sleep(10000) // 10 secs
  // do service B call stuff
}
```

[More on @Async with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) also [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

Beware though, since these calls will be running these `serviceCallB()` logic in new threads, and if used without proper control, might cause memory issues & kill your server.

Comment: As you are using spring-boot annotate with @EnableAsync for `@Async` to be used

Comment: this means the thread is consumed (i.e. taken from the thread pool) for the entire 10 seconds.

Comment: What if `serviceCallB` is a library function that I cannot annotate?

Comment: @MichielHaisma easy, just put the library method call into the `serviceCallB()` method?

Comment: @buræquete Ideally, I don't use an intermediate method. I settled on using a TaskScheduler and passing in a date + a time offset.

Comment: straightforward - without explaining caveats -  can be quite dangerous.

Comment: @anzaan I was not planning to detail what async is, was just giving a solution to the requirement. I added some extra detail to satisfy you, but do let me know what else do you think that can be added! Thanks!